# How to discern between a Javascript object's methods and its properties if they share the same name?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following classes, which are designed to build an email template for me.

**EmailBuilder.js class**

```
const Email = require("./Email");

class EmailBuilder {

    templateId(templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        return new Email(this);
    }
}
```

**Email.js Class**

```
class Email {
    constructor(builder) {
        if (!builder.templateId) {
            throw new Error("You need a templateId");
        }
        this.templateId = builder.templateId;
    }

}

module.exports = Email;
```

When I call the following line, I want an exception to be thrown, because a templateId was not provided, which is required.

```
const email = new EmailBuilder().build();
```

However, this doesn't occur because in the Email class, `builder.templateId` is a function and therefore not falsey.

So the problem here is that my object's property (templateId) in the EmailBuilder.js class shares the same name as the object's method (templateId()).

**What is the best way to adjust my code to solve this problem? Should I just change the name of either the property (templateId) or method (templateId) i.e. make the property `_templateId` and the function `templateId`? Is there a way of distinguishing between an object's properties and the object's methods in Javascript that I'm not aware of?**

Note that EmailBuilder is a builder and therefore it is called in the following manner.

```
const email = new EmailBuilder()
   .templateId("Some templateId")
   .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have non-method properties and method properties with the same name on the same object.¹ They're all just properties, and you can only have one property with a given name.

Instead:

1. Have the caller assign to `templateId` directly
2. Use an accessor property with a [private field](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) (brand new, not quite in the spec yet):

   ```
   class EmailBuilder {
       #templateId: number;
   //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

       set templateId(templateId) {
           this.#templateId = templateId;
   //           ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
           return this;
       }

       // You might have a getter here as well
       get templateId() {
           return this.#templateId;
       }

       build() {
           return new Email(this);
       }
   }
   ```

   JavaScript private fields are finding their way into implementations now, and for environments that don't have them yet, can be used via a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).
3. Use Java-like setter naming (not a popular option)

   ```
   setTemplateId(templateId) {
       this.templateId = templateId;
       return this;
   }
   ```

---

¹ *"You can't have non-method properties and method properties with the same name on the same object."* Okay, so, *technically*, you weren't trying to do that. :-D Technically, you had a `templateId` method on one object (`EmailBuilder.prototype`) and you were putting a `templateId` property on another object (the instance created by `new EmailBuilder`). *Technically*, you can do that, but in practical terms using the method once you've created the data property on the instance is far too convoluted for real-world code, because the instance property shadows the prototype method. For code to reliably get the method, it would need to do this:

```
const email = new EmailBuilder();
Object.getPrototypeOf(email).templateId.call(email, "someId");
```

I think we can probably agree that's just too much hassle...

```js
// I really don't suggest doing this

class EmailBuilder {

    templateId(templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
        return this;
    }

    build() {
        return new Email(this);
    }
}

const email = new EmailBuilder();
console.log(email.templateId);      // "templateId(templateId) { this.templateId = templateId; return this; }"
email.templateId("someId");         // Works, but...
try {
    email.templateId("anotherId");  // Fails
} catch (e) {
}
Object.getPrototypeOf(email).templateId.call(email, "aThirdId");  // Works, but...blech
console.log(email.templateId);      // "aThirdId"
```

Comment: Right, are there any popular conventions to get around this problem? I know underscores are common to signify a variable is private. Is that pretty much the only way to go?

Comment: @user8888 - I've added a few.

Comment: Thanks for the options! Very enlightening. Interesting you mention that the Java-like setter is not a popular option. Is there any particular reason why?

Comment: @user8888 - Since JavaScript got true getters and setters it just seems (anecdotally!) not to be that popular an option, at least no in the pure `setName`/`getName` form. But I could be mischaracterizing it...

Comment: @user8888 - Since I'm me, I've added a bit of arcana at the end of the answer as well. ;-)

Comment: hahah thanks for that :) and I agree with you on "that's too much hassle..."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like templateId is a getter and should be renamed getTemplateId.

or rather you could create a setter for the email builder and use the super keyword to inherit the id from the template.